# Resources for Rocket propulsion

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, rocket-science, propulsion

I am a Mechanical Engineering student who is very much interested in Rocket propulsion. Lately I have been searching for good resources to learn concepts about rocket propulsion. I'd be glad to get some suggestions on where to get started with the subject and what are the different domains I need to learn in order to get a good grasp of the subject.

Comment: Kerbal Space Program

Comment: The ultimate top best resource I'm aware of is the membership of our sister site [space.se].

Comment: Try Sutton and Biblarz's "Rocket Propulsion Elements".